# How would I be able to utilize jsp to run an existing java file?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, tomcat

I have an existing Java program that utilizes Hibernate for database storage. I want to be able to run this program from a webpage, but I'm lost on how to actually do that in a way where I can retrieve the information and display it as a web page. I've already got Tomcat set up as the web server, but I'm not sure how to set up the JSP file so that I can get the information. I'm trying not to have to redo all the work I've already set up, if possible.

Code for Main Class:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                ToDoList todo=new ToDoList(); //creating new ToDoList Object
                Configuration con = new Configuration().configure();
                con.addAnnotatedClass(ToDoList.class);
                SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();
                Session session = sf.openSession();
                Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
                
                int flag=0; 
                while(flag==0){
                
                System.out.print("\n----------To do list----------\n\n1.Add item\n2.Delete item\n3.List of todo Item\n4.exit\nEnter your choice:");
                Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in); //reading choice from user
                int option=input.nextInt(); input.nextLine();
                if(option==1){
                        System.out.println("Enter the item:");
                        String item=input.nextLine();
                        todo.addItem(item);
                        session.save(todo);
                        tx.commit();
                        System.out.println("1 item added!");
        }
        else if(option==2){
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ToDoList.class);
            List<ToDoList> list = criteria.list();
            for(ToDoList test: list) {
                System.out.println(test.getId() + " " + test.getItem());
            }
                System.out.println("Enter item number to delete");
                int n=input.nextInt();
                Object persistentInstance = session.load(ToDoList.class, n);
                if (persistentInstance != null) {
                    
                    session.remove(persistentInstance);
                    tx.commit();
                }
        }
        else if(option==3){
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ToDoList.class);
            List<ToDoList> list = criteria.list();
            for(ToDoList test: list) {
                System.out.println(test.getId() + ": " + test.getItem());
            }

            }else{flag=1;}}
        
       }
}
```

Code for List Class:

```
class ToDoList{ //class ToDoList
    
@Transient
ArrayList<String> todo = new ArrayList<String>(); //ArrayList of Strings for storing todo Item

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,generator="native")
@GenericGenerator(name = "native",strategy = "native")
private int id;
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getItem() {
    return item;
}

String item;

public  void addItem(String item){ //function for adding item
        this.todo.add(item);
        this.item = item;
}

public void deleteItem(int num){ //function for deleting item
        this.todo.remove(num);
}
        
public void listAll(){ //function for listing all items
        for (int i = 0; i < this.todo.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println((i+1)+"."+this.todo.get(i));
    }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to add the javascript tag?

Comment: You can store Object in request with `request.setAttribute` and access them in jsp with `${requestScope.attrName}`